# Get Reference to Original Google Advanced Map Marker in Click Event

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-advanced-marker-element

I am creating a class to launch a modal with an embedded Google map having various functionality. One of the methods is to add an Advanced Map Marker upon click, and then remove it upon subsequent click. Since these markers are added through a click event, they are essentially anonymous. When a marker is clicked after added, it sends an event with the following parameters `{ domEvent, latLng }`.

My question is, how do I reference the original Marker object that was created upon clicking the Map so that I may remove it?

Here’s a simple example:

```js
class MapModal {

 map;

 constructor() {
  this.initMap(); // we'll assume this inits the google map api
  this.map.addListener('click', (evt) => this.#addMarker(evt));
 }

 #addMarker(evt) {
  const marker = new AdvancedMarkerElement({
   map: this.map,
   position: evt.latLng,
  });
  marker.addListener('click', (evt) => this.#evtMarkerClick(evt));
 }

 #evtMarkerClick(evt) {
  const target = evt.domEvent.target; // a <path> element
  // now I need a reference to remove it:
  const theOriginalMarker = ?;
  theOriginalMarker.map = null;
 }
  
 initMap() {
  // do init stuff
 }
}
```

I get that I can wrap the marker click event within the method like so:

```js
#addMarker(evt) {
 const marker = new AdvancedMarkerElement({
  map: this.map,
  position: evt.latLng,
 });
 const event = marker.addEventListener('click', (evt) => {
  // listener is nested
  marker.map = null;
  google.maps.event.removeListener(event);
  
 });
}
```

And also, I can assign a method directly as an Event listener and use the 'this' keyword:

```js
marker.addListener('click', this.#evtMarkerClick);
#evtMarkerClick(evt) {
 const marker = this;
 // now I lose reference to the class instance
}
```

This may be the way I end up doing it, but I would really like to know how to reference the original object for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `AdvancedMarker` class provides the `addEventListener` method but registers this with `gmp-click` as the event type. Using that method means you can easily access custom properties assigned to the marker via the `event.target` interface. So:

If you were to add a new method to your `MapModal` class like this:

```
createid(){
    return window.URL.createObjectURL( new Blob( [] ) ).split('/').pop()
}
```

That method will generate a pretty good unique ID which can be assigned to each marker as a custom property/attribute - such as `id`

The `addMarker` method:

```
addMarker(evt) {
    const id=this.createid();   // create the custom id property
    
    const marker = new AdvancedMarkerElement({
        map: this.map,
        position: evt.latLng,
    });
    marker.id=id;
    marker.addEventListener('gmp-click', this.evtMarkerClick );
    
    this.markers[ id ]=marker;
}
```

Then you could change the `evtMarkerClick` method like this:

```
evtMarkerClick(e) {
    const theOriginalMarker = this.markers[ e.target.id ];
    console.log( e.target.id, theOriginalMarker );
    this.markers[ id ].setMap( null );
    delete this.markers[ id ];      
}
```

[a proof of concept](https://jsfiddle.net/RamRaider/7fzL8g9j/7/)

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I had a feeling it was something like this, though I kinda wish that Google had built in a method similar to Bootstrap where they have a .getInstance(elem) method. I’m curious, how does the createObjectURL method generate a unique id from what is essentially the same input?

Comment: the inner workings of `Blob` are, I will happily admit, something of a mystery - I adapted code discovered ages ago to create that function and never investigated why it does what it does ( think I was trying to generate `uuid` values or similar )